# Based on the result from the table, get the result from another table

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables users and products:

1) users:

```
 id |  username    | ... |
--------------------------
 1  | user1name 1  | ... |
 2  | user2name 2  | ... |
 3  | user3name 4  | ... |
 4  | user4name 5  | ... |
```

2) products:

```
id |  product_name   | user_id |
--------------------------------
 1 |  product1name 1 |    1    |
 2 |  product2name 2 |    1    |
 3 |  product3name 3 |    2    |
 4 |  product4name 4 |    3    |
```

I want to get products based on the result from the users table. I have a user table connection with a product table.

My request:

```
SELECT P.*
    FROM PRODUCTS AS P
        LEFT JOIN USERS AS U ON (U.USER_ID = P.USER_ID)
            WHERE LOWER(U.USERNAME) LIKE LOWER('%use1r%')
                    GROUP BY P.PRODUCT_ID, U.USER_ID
```

What answer I expect to receive:

```
id |  product_name   | user_id |
--------------------------------
 1 |  product1name 1 |    1    |
 2 |  product2name 2 |    1    |
```

Comment: How this condition would be true? `U.USER_ID = P.STORE_ID`. I think it should be `U.USER_ID = P.USER_ID`.

Comment: The `GROUP BY` seems pretty useless - what is the purpose of that? Also `%use1r%` won't match any rows - did you mean to write `%user1%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the condition on the username into the JOIN condition. Applying a WHERE condition on the outer joined table turns your outer join back into an inner join.

Additionally - given your sample data - `%use1r%` won't match any row, I assume you meant to write `%user1%`. As you query only returns columns from the `products` table, I *think* you meant to use `p.user_id` in the `group by` as ell to remove duplicate products that stem from the join.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products AS p
  LEFT JOIN users AS U ON u.user_id = p.user_id
                      AND LOWER(u.username) LIKE LOWER('%use1r%') --<< HERE
GROUP BY p.product_id, p.user_id;
```

But given your expected output, it seems you want an inner join as you only want products assigned to the matching user.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products AS p
  JOIN users AS U ON u.user_id = p.user_id
                 AND LOWER(u.username) LIKE LOWER('%use1r%') --<< HERE
GROUP BY p.product_id, p.user_id;
```

With an inner join it doesn't matter where you put the condition on the `username`. The above is equivalent to:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products AS p
  JOIN users AS U ON u.user_id = p.user_id
WHERE LOWER(u.username) LIKE LOWER('%use1r%') --<< HERE
GROUP BY p.product_id, p.user_id;
```

---

But given your usage of the `group by` I wonder if you are trying to remove duplicate products from the result. In that case an EXISTS query is maybe what you really want

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products AS p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM users u
              WHERE u.user_id = p.user_id
                AND LOWER(u.username) LIKE LOWER('%use1r%'));
```

Then you don't need to remove unwanted duplicates with a `group by`